# git: reviewing changes after 'git fetch'

Tags: git, git-log, git-fetch

Following a git fetch, I'd like to review code changes that are introduced from upstream.

I can use `git log -p ..@{u}`, however the output will not include diffs of merge commits/merges of pull requests.

Is there a way to include those in the output, that will yield a comprehensive history of changes that occurred since I last pulled?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `git log -p` to view commits as patches, it does—as you noticed—skip merge commits when it comes time to diff them.  That is, it shows you the log *message* as usual, but no diff at all.

You have three options for controlling this:

- `-c` (one hyphen and one lowercase C): show one form of combined diff
- `--cc` (two hyphens and two lowercase Cs): show the other form of combined diff
- `-m`: "split" each merge, showing a patch against *each* parent.  In this case you will see the log message twice.

The combined diff format is described in [a separate section of the `git diff` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html#_combined_diff_format) (and several others that share this file).  For some reason, though,<sup>1</sup> a key fact is [hidden in this earlier section](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html#_diff_format_for_merges):

> Note that *combined diff* lists only files which were modified from all parents.

Quite often this is actually what you want: if the merge kept file `README.txt` the same as the `README.txt` in either parent commit, it's probably not interesting to show a diff against the other parent commit.  If you are not expecting this, however, it can be quite a surprise.  The only way to defeat it is to use `-m`.

---

<sup>1</sup>This makes some sense for `git diff-tree`, `git diff-files`, and `git diff --raw` as the section itself is describing the *files that will be listed*, and files that match at least one parent will not be listed.  However, if you haven't memorized this little fact and are just searching the documentation for the immediate next two sections ("generating patches with `-p`" and "combined diff format"), the key sentence will probably not even be in your window.  I still remember being burned by this, however many years later it is now. :-)

Comment: `git log ..@{u} -p -m --first-parent` gives all the info I require. I'd note that the mentioning of the combined diff options (-c/--c) where a bit of a throw-off: because they do not generate diffs for files identical to that of any parent, changes in merges that are accepted as-is do not appear in the output. I think accepting someone else's changes in a pull request is more-often-than-not the common case. At any rate, `-p -m --first-parent` seems to do the job. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I kind of wish there were a combined-diff option that still showed files that matched one (or more than one, but not both/all) parent(s), and that *this* (nonexistent) option were the default.